# libboost_date_time linker error

Tags: c++, boost, cygwin, boost-date-time

I just built and installed boost on cygwin and was trying to compile a program but it gave me a linker error because it was looking for `libboost_date_time`, and I have `libboost_date_time-mt` instead in usr/local/lib
I tried to reinstall boost using the following (the same command I had used initially)

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=chrono,date_time,exception,filesystem,graph,graph_parallel,iostreams,math,program_options,random,serialization,signals,system,test,thread,wave  link=static link=shared threading=single threading=multi
```

but I get the error:

```
bash: ./bootstrap.sh: no such file or directory
```

any idea why the build wouldn't have worked with the ./boostrap command above the first time, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Which directory are you in when you ran the bootstrap commands?

Comment: my home directory, i.e. /home/ba

Comment: Do you have a bootstrap.sh anywhere on the disk?

Comment: yes indeed....it shows up in 2 places C:\cygwin\home\ba\boost_1_47_0\tools\build\v2 and C:\cygwin\home\ba\boost_1_47_0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`./bootstrap.sh` means run the shell script bootstrap.sh in the cirrent directory.

So you need to be in the sirectory the script is in So

```
cd C:\cygwin\home\ba\boost_1_47_0
```

and then run the bootstrap script

An alternative is to install boost via [cygwin itself](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=libboost-devel/libboost-devel-1.43.0-1&grep=boost) if you can use 1.43

Comment: ok, I understand. I am running it from there and it works. thx!

Comment: so, I ran that and then I ran ./b2  --layout=tagged and it failed updating 2 targets and skipped 7 targets....I then ran ./b2  --layout=tagged install and now I look in my /usr/local/lib directory and I still have only the files with suffix -mt. what have I missed?

Comment: I would just build the lot using --build-type=complete and not try to do the complex compile line

Comment: so, if I understand correctly, I should just do ./boostrap.sh --build-type=complete and then run ./b2 --layout=tagged followed by ./b2 --layout=tagged install

Comment: I would do a clean first so it stars from scratch

Comment: sorry for the basic question, but does that mean I go and delete boost_1_47_0 in C:\cygwin\home\ba

Comment: No see the bjam tutorial - try bjam --clean debug release

Comment: I ran bjam --clean debug release followed by ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=all followed by ./b2, and I still only see the -mt libraries.